# Two step equations $-1=5+x/6$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I need help turning $x$ into a negative number to solve

> $$-1=5+x/6$$

The problem looks easy, but I'm missing something and I can't figure it out

Comment: You'll need to do almost exactly the same thing that we did in [your previous post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/365800/solving-a-two-step-equation-6x-4-5). Think about what we did there, and apply it here.

Answer (score 3):

If you have
$$a = b + \dfrac{x}c$$
Subtract $b$ from both sides to get
$$-b + a = -b + b + \dfrac{x}c = \dfrac{x}c \tag{$\star$}$$
Now multiply $(\star)$ by $c$ on both sides to get
$$c \times(-b+a) = c \times \dfrac{x}c = x \implies x = c(-b+a)$$

[I got reminded of this.](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5ZED4gITL28)